# npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk throwing error

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am a beginner to mean stack and I am trying to install angular material, but Powershell throws this error. [image]

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you try [`ng add @angular/material`](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#install-angular-material)?

Comment: It results a similar page of many npm err!

Comment: Have you tried running the command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps?

Comment: have you tried 'npm install' in the scripts folder (no package names after it) or 'npm update' (also with no package names after it) to install missing packages prior to attempting again to install @angular/material?  https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-update